# Android ¿cómo reducir tamaño de un bitmap?

Tags: android, android-studio, bitmap

Tengo una aplicación que permite al usuario cambiar su imagen de perfil por alguna otra que tenga almacenada en su dispositivo. Para ello, la aplicación envía la imagen seleccionada a un servidor remoto. Todo esto funciona bien, así que no pongo el código de esa parte para no complicar la pregunta. Mi problema es que quiero que esa imagen que envíe al servidor se reduzca de tamaño para impedir, por ejemplo, archivos grandes de cinco o seis megas, que ralentizan mucho la aplicación. Pero no me termina de salir bien.

Así tengo el código:

```
if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            imagepath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);

            ByteArrayOutputStream bytearrayoutputstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            //Redimensiona la imagen antes de redondearla
            Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 150, 150, false);

            resizedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,50,bytearrayoutputstream);


            //Redondear la imagen
            int min = Math.min(resizedBitmap.getWidth(), resizedBitmap.getHeight());

            Bitmap bitmapRounded = Bitmap.createBitmap(min, min, resizedBitmap.getConfig());

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapRounded);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setShader(new BitmapShader(resizedBitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
            canvas.drawRoundRect((new RectF(0.0f, 0.0f, min, min)), min / 2, min / 2, paint);

            //al terminar el proceso, carga la imagen en el ImageView correspondiente
            avatar.setImageBitmap(bitmapRounded);

}
```

El bitmap lo intento redimensionar (esto funciona bien), después lo intento reducir de tamaño (no funciona) y, por último, redondeo la imagen (también funciona bien) antes de ajustarla al ImageView correspondiente.

Lo único que no consigo que me funcione correctamente es reducir el tamaño de la imagen.

Alguna sugerencia? Gracias.

Comment: ¿Que quieres decir con "reducir de tamaño no funciona"? te da algún error en esa momento o simplemente no consigues que la imagen pese menos de lo esperado?

Comment: Lo segundo. Error no me da ninguno. La imagen sube bien al servidor. Pero no se le reduce el tamaño. Pesa lo mismo que si no intentara reducirle el tamaño.

Comment: Has probado a comprimir la imagen como último paso? quizá el redondeo de la imagen deshaga la compresión previa.

Comment: He probado lo que comentas, que ahora que lo has dicho me ha parecido lo más lógico, pero no parece funcionar tampoco. Es muy raro, la verdad.

Comment: Prueba con valores máximo y mínimo, es decir comprimiendo al 0% y al 100%, deberías obtener imágenes con tamaños diferentes; de ser así es posible que la imagen ya esté en el umbral del 50% y no se pueda comprimir más la información. Lo digo pro probar, desconozco el funcionamiento interno de la compresión jpg y su parametrización.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para reducir el tamaño en bytes debes revisar estos métodos los cuales estas en realidad usando en tu programa:

Puedes usar el redimensionamiento del bitmap al ser creado cuando haces uso del método **[createScaledBitmap(Bitmap, int, int, boolean)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean))**, aquí puedes reducir el ancho y alto del bitmap :

```
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 100 /*Ancho*/, 100 /*Alto*/, false /* filter*/);
```

Importante considerar el valor del parámetro `filter`:

> **filter**: Se debe utilizar o no el filtrado bilineal al escalar el mapa
>   de bits. Si es `true`, se utilizará el filtrado bilineal al
>   escalar, que tiene una mejor calidad de imagen al costo de un peor
>   rendimiento. Si es `false`, entonces se usa la escala del vecino más
>   cercano, que tendrá una peor calidad de imagen pero es más rápida. El
>   valor predeterminado recomendado es establecer el filtro en
>   "verdadero", ya que el costo del filtrado bilineal suele ser mínimo y
>   la calidad de imagen mejorada es significativa.

También puedes cambiar la calidad de la imagen al crear el bitmap, lo cual también reduce el tamaño mediante **[compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat format, int quality, OutputStream stream)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.CompressFormat.html)**:

```
 resizedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,40 /*Calidad*/,bytearrayoutputstream);
```

Estos dos métodos permiten que al crear tu bitmap  este reduzca su tamaño en bytes.

Comment: Muchas gracias Elenasys. Como siempre, es usted un pozo de sabiduría!